# how to save mysql query output to a file named (currentTime).csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector-python

i am trying to store the output of mysql query to a file. I need to have a file  with extension .csv and its name should be the current time of my pc  e.g: **2015-03-26 19:26:13.065000**.csv.
when i execute this query

```
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='',host='localhost',database='ER_PC_NK')    
exe2 = conn.cursor()       
exe2.execute("""SELECT tbl_site.Site_name, State_Code, Country_Code,Street_Address, instrum_start_date, instrum_end_date, Comment INTO OUTFILE  'myrecord.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' FROM tbl_site JOIN tbl_site_monit_invent ON site_id = tbl_Site_site_id""")
```

first time it saved a file named myrecord.csv but second time NOT.After a long search on the internet i found that it cannot override the file myrecord.csv, so i decided to name the file as currentTime.csv, to do this i thought to try this kind of thing:

```
    ss=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%i_%s');

    SET @t1=1
    set @FOLDER = 'c:/tmp/';
    SET @PREFIX = 'orders';
    SET @EXT    = '.csv';

    SET @CMD = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM orders INTO OUTFILE '",@FOLDER,@PREFIX,@TS,@EXT,
        "' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"'",
        "  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';");

    PREPARE statement FROM @CMD
```

but found an error: user defined variables are not defined, again googled and found [user defined variables are available from Connector/NET version 5.2.2](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) while i'm using MySQL Connector Python v2.0.3 for python v2.7

i am very confused, if you have more better solution please tell. Your effort will be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of user defined variables you can just do

```
import datetime
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='',host='localhost',database='ER_PC_NK')    
exe2 = conn.cursor()       
exe2.execute(
   """SELECT tbl_site.Site_name, State_Code, Country_Code,
      Street_Address, instrum_start_date, instrum_end_date,
      Comment INTO OUTFILE  %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY
      ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
      FROM tbl_site JOIN tbl_site_monit_invent ON site_id = tbl_Site_site_id
   """, (str(datetime.datetime.now()),))
```

Comment: when i run this query it gives an error                                             **DatabaseError: 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '2015-04-06 20:48:33.418000' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)**.                                     I took help from                              http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-create.html                  but this cannot resolve,                                                                               and thanks for considering my problem.